# Joining columns with no central key source table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following tables:

```
+---------------------+
|   Item_Color_Meta   |
+---------------------+
| ID      |   value   |
+---------------------+
|   1     |   'red'   |
|   4     |   'blue'  |
+---------------------+

+---------------------+
|   Item_Height_Meta  |
+---------------------+
| ID      |   value   |
+---------------------+
|   1     |   '2inch' |
|   2     |   '7inch' |
|   6     |   '12inch'|
+---------------------+
```

I have a number of these tables that hold and ID and a value. I would like to create a result set that returns a line for all Id's with a column from each tables, so in the case above the result would look like so:

```
ID               Color_Meta                Height_Meta
1                  'red'                     '2inch'
2                   NULL                     '7inch'
4                  'blue'                    NULL
6                   NULL                     '12inch'
```

The issue I have is with the join statements, What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `full outer join`

```
select
    isnull(ICM.ID, IHM.ID) as ID, ICM.Color_Meta, IHM.Height_Meta
from Item_Color_Meta as ICM
    full outer join Item_Height_Meta as IHM on IHM.ID = ICM.ID
```

If you have more than 2 table, you may consider smth like this

**update** Yes, I've forgot that MySQL does not support `full outer join`, so this one will work anyway :)

```
select
    A.ID, T1.Column1, T2.Column2, T3.Column3
from 
(
    select TT1.ID from Table1 as TT1 union
    select TT2.ID from Table2 as TT2 union
    select TT3.ID from Table3 as TT3
) as A
    left outer join Table1 as T1 on T1.ID = A.ID
    left outer join Table2 as T2 on T2.ID = A.ID
    left outer join Table3 as T3 on T3.ID = A.ID
```

This syntax is very easy to modify and you can add additional tables

Check [**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae7f/1)

Comment: MySQL does not support full outer join

Comment: Hmm, not sure if MySQL has full outer joins

Comment: Yes, I've changed an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  id
,       min(Color_Meta)
,       min(Height_Meta)
from    (
        select  id
        ,       value as Color_Meta
        ,       null as Height_Meta
        from    Item_Color_Meta 
        union all
        select  id
        ,       null
        ,       value
        from    Item_Height_Meta
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        id
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21356/2/0)

Comment: Suppose you have 20 tables. Your query will be really huge. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    select c.id, c.val Color_Meta, h.val Height_Meta
    from Item_Color_Meta c
    left outer join Item_Height_Meta h on c.id = h.id

    UNION

    select h.id, c.val Color_Meta, h.val Height_Meta
    from Item_Height_Meta h
    left outer join Item_Color_Meta c on c.id = h.id
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you'd get two rows for id 1 using this solution

Comment: Try write this one for 10 tables :) I think it become very hard to read

Comment: @Andomar, the `union` will eliminate the duplication. Please see this fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1883b/3).